# Python "valueless" dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, time-complexity

I have a problem where I want to keep track over a large number of values. If I never encountered the value, I'll do action A, otherwise - action B. Naturally, I considered using dictionary to keep track of the values, since the lookup is fast, ~O(1).

However, dictionary is a key-value system, while all I want to take advantage of, is the key.
I can assign a bogus value

```
"myvalue": None
```

but I can't help but wonder if there's a more elegant way to go about it.

Thoughts? Ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment: Why to add the key to the dictionary at all then?

Comment: Add a key - to know I've encountered it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set) is for:

```
members = set()
members.add("mykey")
members.add("otherkey")

if "mykey" in members:
  . . .
```

Comment: Oh - great, that solves two problems indeed. 'in set' is implemented with a hash table right? So I can expect to get ~O(1)

Comment: @Ruslan It has, afaik, the same performance guarentees as dictionaries. It may even be implemented using a dictionary. In Java, iirc, their HashSet is just a HashMap that automatically maps the keys to `null`. For convenience, I wouldn't be surprised if Python does the same.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Semantically, a set is a dict with `None` values. The implementation is probably a little more streamlined, since it doesn't actually need to store the `None`s.

Answer (score 1):

If I were to stick to your dict implementation, I would:

```
if value in dict:
    #Action B
else:
    #Action A
    dict[value] = 1
```

so that you wouldn't need to save unseen values in your dict in the first place.

Comment: I think that the in dict is implemented O(n), right? So I'd try to avoid that

Comment: @Ruslan `in` is very fast for dictionaries. You'll only get O(n) if you a massive amount of hash collisions afaik.

Comment: @Ruslan See [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Comment: @Ruslan In Python 2, `if value in dict.keys()` would have been O(n), since `keys` just returned a list, so `list.__contains__` would have been used. `dict.__contains__` is O(1). In Python 3, even `value in dict.keys()` would be O(1), as `keys` returns a special set-like object.

Answer (score 1):

The best suited for your task is [frozenset()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset).

> The `frozenset` type is immutable and hashable — its contents cannot be
>   altered after it is created; it can therefore be used as a dictionary
>   key or as an element of another set.

```
members = frozenset([keylist])
    if "mykey" in members:
```

Based on your question, this is the best suited collection form for your task in python.

Comment: One of the actions I do once I encounter a new value, is to update the set, so I'm not sure immutable types qualify here. I didn't specify about my "action A" or "action B" so sorry for the misunderstanding. Good to be reminded of frozen set though

Comment: @Ruslan All right, my pleasure, though if you found my answer useful you can give it an up, to help the future reader.